# Использование include в Django

Tags: python, django, jinja2

Имеется следующая задача: Есть несколько HTML-страниц, у которых есть футер с ссылками на социальные сети (твиттер, вконтакте и т.д.). И эта информация располагается на всех страницах. Пользователь через админку (Django) может выбрать, какие поля на соц. сети заполнить, чтобы они потом отобразились на сайте.

Так вот: можно ли вынести футер в отдельный template-шаблон, а затем подключить его на все страницы?

В шаблоне будет примерно следующее:

```
{% if vk %}
    {#  здесь располагается иконка  #}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Всем большое спасибо за ответы. Попробую реализовать один из методов.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Во-первых, в Django принято выносить общие для всех страниц в отдельный файл, обычно именуемый `base.html`. Выглядит он примерно так:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <!-- что-нибудь ещё -->
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <!-- шапка -->
</header>
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
<footer>
    <!-- подвал -->
</footer>
<!-- Здесь, например, скрипты -->
</body>
</html>
```

В отдельных страницах сайта (например, `index.html`) наследуемся от этого шаблона и заменяем содержимое блоков:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Главная страница{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Добро пожаловать на такой-то сайт!</h1>
<!-- ну и всё остальное тоже тут -->
{% endblock %}
```

Этим решается первая часть проблемы — вынос кода футера в отдельный шаблон.

---

Вторая часть — как в этот общий шаблон запихнуть информацию из админки. Способов есть несколько. Про `inclusion_tag` уже рассказали в соседнем ответе, я расскажу про `context_processors`.

Создаём файл `context_processors.py` в каком-нибудь из ваших Django-приложений и пишем туда что-нибудь такое:

```
def social(request):
    # Здесь загружаете вашу информацию из моделей любым удобным
    # для вас способом, я для краткости просто строку напишу
    context = {
        'social_vk': 'https://vk.com/чтототам'
    }

    return context
```

Чтобы он использовался, его нужно включить в настройках. Для этого найдите в вашем `settings.py`, где включается `context_processors` для ваших шаблонов, и допишите туда путь к созданной вами функции (в Python-формате). Должно получиться что-то такое:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'вашеприложение.context_processors.social',

                # Здесь все остальные context processors, не трогаем
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                # ... и так далее
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Если всё сделано правильно, то в каждом шаблоне появятся дополнительные переменные, взятые из того словаря, который возвращает функция `social`. В моём примере это переменная `social_vk`. Соответственно, возвращаемся в `base.html` и получаем там возможность прописать ссылку ВК:

```
<footer>
{% if social_vk %}
    <a href="{{ social_vk }}" target="_blank">Посетите мой ВК!</a>
{% endif %}
</footer>
```

Блоки, имена и типы переменных и всё такое прочее вы, естественно, можете подкорректировать под свои нужды.

---

И не забываем пользоваться [документацией Django](https://djbook.ru/rel1.9/ref/templates/index.html) — всё, что я тут написал, есть и там тоже.

Answer (score 2):

В Django это можно сделать с помощью inclusion_tag.

Краткий алгоритм:

1. в каталоге с проектом создаем подкаталог `templatetags`.
2. в нем создаем файл `__init.py__` (можно пустой, главное - чтобы был), чтобы каталог мог использоваться как модуль;
3. в каталоге `templatetags` создаем файл (например, `tags.py`) примерно такого содержания (обратите внимание - функция обязательно должна возвращать dict с данными):

   ```
   #coding:utf-8

   from django import template
   from addict import Dict
   register = template.Library()

   def my_new_tag(context):
     # DO SOMETHING
     return data

   register.inclusion_tag('template_folder/project/template.html', takes_context=True)(my_new_tag)
   ```
4. создаем шаблон в Вашей папке с шаблонами (как указано выше - `template_folder/project/template.html`) с требуемым функционалом;
5. подключаем в шаблоне в нужном месте свежесозданный тег (называется так же, как и функция выше):
   `{% my_new_tag %}`

Comment: Ну и кроме того, используйте наследование шаблонов, возможно, Вам и его хватит

Comment: Вот про наследование шаблонов по-моему крайне желательно написать подробнее

Comment: @andreymal, дак это, можно сказать, базовый функционал, в любой книжке описан в деталях. Грубо говоря - создается базовая html-страница (например, maintemplate.html), с данными, которые должны быть на всех страницах (как раз типа шапки, меню, футера и т.п.), затем, с помощью конструкций {% block name_of_block %}{%endblock%} обозначаются места, где могут быть другие данные, и в дочерних шаблонах с помощью {% extends 'maintemplate.html' %} и тех же {% block name_of_block %}{%endblock%} подставляется необходимое

Comment: @stxdtm Дополните последним комментарием свой ответ, очень полезная информация.

Comment: @Klimenkomud, в соседнем ответе весьма доходчиво расписали уже:)

Answer (score 1):

Не просто можно, а нужно. Тебе достаточно взять какой-то готовый шаблонизатор или сделать свой. А можешь просто формировать страничку из отдельных кусков, но ты быстро в них запутаешься.

Comment: Подскажите, как это можно реализовать? Как передать модель, чтобы обратиться к полям?

Comment: В Django уже встроен шаблонизатор. И у этого шаблонизатора уже есть include.

Answer (score 1):

Из документации следует такое заключение:
В месте, где вы делаете рендеринг - передайте в контекст темплейта нужную модель, выглядеть это будет примерно так:

```
yourModelObjectHere = new yourSuperModel() // Или любой другой путь получения вашего объекта(из БД, например)
template = Template("My name is {{ user.name }}.")
output = template.render(Context({"user":yourModelObjectHere}))
```

Comment: С помощью include это не получится реализовать?

Comment: Получится, просто тогда в том месте, где вы рендерите родительский темплейт(я предполагаю, что вы подключаете куски в шаблон(нужные), а потом делаете рендер всего этого добра) - передавайте в контекст вашу модель, и используйте её в темплейте как показано в моём ответе.